# Cannot boot a Windows UEFI installation with Intel Graphics HD 4000 without CSM

Tags: windows-8, boot, motherboard, uefi, intel-graphics

## Problem

I am attempting to convert my Windows 8.1 Pro installation from BIOS to UEFI. I followed [these](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14286.converting-windows-bios-installation-to-uefi.aspx) instructions. However, I cannot boot without the enabling the Compatibility Support Module (CSM). Windows boots fine in UEFI with CSM.

The motherboard emits an audible error code (`long` `short` `short` `short` `short`) and does not output a display signal. I am using Intel HD Graphics 4000 with a DVI-to-HDMI cable. I booted with CSM and updated the Intel Graphics Driver to 10.18.10.3345 and the motherboard's BIOS to 1301, yet the problem persists.

Interestingly enough, I installed a discrete Gigabyte GTX 670 and I could not boot without CSM enabled, either. However, instead of an audible error message, it somehow output an on-screen message that the GPU does not support UEFI. I upgraded the discrete graphics BIOS, and hence forth, could boot in pure UEFI without CSM!

I am to understand that in order to disable CSM, the graphics chip must support UEFI. According to my research, Intel Graphics HD 4000 should support UEFI boot. I do not know what version BIOS Intel Graphics HD 4000 is currently running, but I assume it would be updated with the latest driver.

How can I boot in pure UEFI without CSM with Intel Graphics HD 4000?

## Relevant specs

- Windows 8.1 Pro
- Asus P8Z77-V LK
- Intel Core i5-3570K

Comment: Why do you want to disable CSM exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound Because it should work without it.

Comment: What does the beep codes mean.  I would also post on the ASUS community forums I have found them to be very helpful

Comment: I too have this exact some issue with my Gigabyte Z77X-D3H motherboard and i5-3570K processor. Dedicated graphics cards works appropriately after the post code and device manager shows the intel graphics device working correctly but no capability to display. Commenting to gain some visibility.